# Which character encoding should I use for Tab-delimited flat file?

Tags: c#, encoding, amazon-mws

We are calling Report Type ‘_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_’ of MWS API using C# web Application.
Some times we got � Character instead of single quote, space or for any other special characters while encoding data. 
We have used `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` method to encode StreamReader.
We are using below code.

```
Stream s = reportRequest.Report;
StreamReader stream_reader = new StreamReader(s);
string reportResponseText = stream_reader.ReadToEnd();

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(reportResponseText);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
StreamReader filestream = new StreamReader(stream);
```

We also have tried ‘Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reportResponseText)’ but not useful.

Could anyone please suggest us correct method to encode data in correct format?

Comment: If you don't know what encoding was used when *creating* the file (and it could be, literally, anything) then you're out of luck if you're not able to guess it. Different encodings can produce the same sequences of bytes, but the *meaning* of those bytes entirely depends on the encoding.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are absolutely right. I already I have created Ticket with MWS Support but not getting any response. And that's why I have asked this question over here with tag 'amazon-mws' and with hope some one may knows 'What encoding was used when creating ‘_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_’ report type using MWS API